# JavaBean Introspection in Servlets [Tomcat]

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags, javabeans

What is the equivalent "servlet code" for this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="beans.UserBean" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>
```

Tomcat translates this to:

```
beans.UserBean user = null;
synchronized (session) {
    user = (beans.UserBean) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("user", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
    if (user == null) {
        user = new beans.UserBean();
        _jspx_page_context.setAttribute("user", user, PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
    }
}

org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect(_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("user"), request);
```

Is there no other way of easily doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each jsp compiler will yield different results. Using the [commons beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) it will look something of a sort of

```
for(Enumeration pnames = request.getParameterNames();pnames.hasMoreElements();) {
  String name = pnames.nextElement();
  BeanUtils.setProperty(bean,name,request.getParameter(name));
}
```

Notice that it does not handle arrays and other special cases.

Also, this is why usually you use a web framework such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/), [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/), [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), etc - it just a boiler plate code, and you have to code your validations anyway.

Comment: Turns out I can use them directly on my servlets. Sorry for not trying before asking. But, I don't think this works if used on another container. Thanks for the link, David.